# sonar package exclusion to increase code coverage

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

tool:SonarQube Scanner 3.2

I wish to exclude some packages from sonar code Coverage where sonar is part of build pipeline of jenkins.

Ways tried (for now added all files under the package mentioned just to check if it really excludes all java file !)
pom.xml

1. `<sonar.coverage.exclusions>com/**/</sonar.coverage.exclusions>`
2. `<sonar.exclusions>{project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/ept/scheduleinterface/dto/**/*, {project/basedir}/src/main/java/com/test/aa//model/</sonar.exclusions>`

jenkinsfile

1. `sonar: [projectKey: PROJECT_NAME, ‘java.libraries’:‘/root/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok//lombok-.jar’,‘sonar.coverage.exclusions’: 'src/main/java/com//’**],`
2. `’-Dsonar.coverage.exclusions’: 'src/main/java/com//’]**`
3. `’-Dsonar.coverage.exclusions’: 'com//*’]**,`

In my project structure there is a jenkinsfile and pom.xml file along with dockerfile.

But it looks is sonar is not obeying the configuration at all.
Also I can see in jenkins console logs the changes I did in e.g. jenkins file are considered

Running shell script:

```
‘-Dsonar.java.libraries=/root/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok//lombok-.jar’ ‘-Dsonar.sonar.coverage.exclusions=src/main/java/com/**/*’ -Dsonar.sources=src -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco.exec -
```

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

you need to put something like below (put both theses properties in your gradle file)

```
sonarqube {
properties {


    /**
     * For detailed meaning of the following exclusion properties, please checkout:
     * https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters
     */
    property "sonar.coverage.exclusions", "**/generated/**/*.java,**/generated-src/**/*.java"
    property "sonar.exclusions", "**/generated/**/*.java,**/generated-src/**/*.java"
}
}
```